# How to refer back to associated index with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, link-to

Doing nested routes for the first time and I cannot figure out the link_to paths for the nested routes that I have. Using rails scaffold for each

```
resources :venues do
     resources :events
   end
```

I edited to have the following in the index.html.erb of the venue model

`<%= link_to 'Events', venue_events_path(venue) %>`

Which brings me to the correct index.html.erb of the events model (venues/1/events)

But I just can't seem to figure out the correct link_to path on the show page of event to bring me back to venues/1/events

With the default scaffold, its 
`<%= link_to 'Back', events_path %>`

I have tried different paths like venue_events_path(venue) but rails keeps saying that it cannot find venue without an ID. 
I am assuming that is because clicking on the default show link brings me to localhost:3000/events/1 instead of localhost:3000/venues/1/events/1

What would be the correct paths for nested attributes besides the difficulty that I am facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nested routes I would use the following setup:

```rb
# routes.rb
resources :venues do
  resources :events
end
```

```rb
# venues controller
class VenuesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @venues = Venue.all
  end

  def show
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

```rb
# venues index.html.erb
<% @venues.each do |venue| %>
  <%= link_to 'Venue', venue_path(venue) %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
# venues show.html.erb
# link to the events index page from the current venue
<%= link_to 'Events', venue_events_path(@venue) %>

# link to each individual event from the current venue
<% @venue.events.each do |event| %>
  <%= link_to 'Event', venue_event_path(@venue, event)
<% end %>
```

```rb
# events controller
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
    @events = @venue.events
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

```rb
# events index.html.erb
# link back to venue
<%= link_to 'Venue', venue_path(@venue) %>

# link to each event
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <%= link_to 'Event', venue_event_path(event.venue, event) %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
# events show.html.erb
# link back to events index
<%= link_to 'Events', venue_events_path(@event.venue) %>

# link back to venue show
<%= link_to 'Venue', venue_path(@event.venue) %>
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if your events have an venue id. You said you have in your event model: `belongs_to :venue, optional: true` the optional true make the venue_id not required for an event. If that is what you want then nested routes doesn't really makes sense, because an NOT nested event is not going to be linked nested.

Comment: Do you also have a single line `resources :events` (not nested) in your routes.rb?

Comment: No I don't. I am just having trouble figuring out the correct paths to and fro the pages

Comment: Actually venue_events_path(@event.venue) does not seem to work. It still says that no route matches and my venue_id is nil, missing required keys : [:venue_id]

I do have `belongs_to :venue, optional: true` , and `def index
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
    @events = @venue.events.all
  end`

Comment: Hey thanks for the awesome answer!  
But i do have an issue with the scaffolding    
`respond_to do |format|  
      if @question.save  
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }  
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }  
      else  
        format.html { render :new }  
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }  
      end  
    end  
  end`    
What do I replace with @question since this is a nested attribute?

Comment: You need to give me some more information for that. Like what is the parent? And what do you want it to do? What should it render and where should it redirect to